# How to merge multiple consecutive click events into the last one?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

In the view, there are two buttons that display a text prompt when clicked, and the display of the text is controlled by the `@State var tipText: String?`. I have written an asynchronous function using the `.task(id:priority:_:)` modifier that shows the text when the user clicks a button, and hides it automatically after three seconds.

```swift
struct SwiftUIView: View {
    @State var tipText: String?

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    Button("Red") {
                        tipText = "Red"
                    }
                    .tint(.red)
                    .controlSize(.large)
                    .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)

                    Button("Blue") {
                        tipText = "Blue"
                    }
                    .tint(.blue)
                    .controlSize(.large)
                    .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
                }

                Spacer()
            }
            .padding()

            // Shows the text when the user clicks a button
            if let tipText = tipText {
                Text(
                    """
                    You have just clicked the \(tipText) button,
                    this prompt will disappear in 3 seconds.
                    """
                )
                .padding()
                .background(.ultraThickMaterial)
                .cornerRadius(10)

                // Close the text prompt after three seconds.
                .task(id: tipText) {
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
                        self.tipText = nil
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, if the user quickly clicks back and forth between the two buttons, the text will disappear early. I suspect that this is because the earlier execution of the asynchronous function caused the text to be hidden prematurely.

[image: Here you can see the effect of the code execution.]

My expectation is that regardless of how many times the user clicks continuously, the text must wait for three seconds after I stop clicking before disappearing. Is there a better way to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.task` is called on appear and is cancelled/restarted every time the `id` param changes so you need logic to handle those cases. Also you'll need a counter e.g.

```
@State var clickCount = 0

Button("Red") {
    tipText = "Red"
    clickCount += 1
}

Button("Blue") {
    tipText = "Blue"
    clickCount += 1
}

.task(id: clickCount) {
    if clickCount == 0 { // return early the first time
        return
    }
    do {
        try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(3)) // exceptions if cancelled because id changed while sleeping.
        tipText = nil
    }
    catch {
        // was cancelled
    }
}
```